# What "girls" is Harley referring to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, birds-of-prey

Renee tries to take Harley Quinn's bulletproof suit:

> Harley Quinn: Oh, no, no, no. Not that one. Sentimental value.  Try
>   this.
>
> Renee: You're kidding.
>
> Harley Quinn: What? Gotta take care of the **girls.**

What "girls" is Harley referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Harley has personified as "girls" anatomical features of mammal females on her chest region that would be prone to bullet hits unless protected by a bulletproof vest.  This may be slang used by real human females too.

Comment: I.e., her breasts.

Comment: Which, admittedly, may not be standard slang for some people. and it's not 100% clear in the film, so it's a reasonable question. Thank you for answering it for them.